# JOLT: transform all json elements of type "array"

Tags: json, jolt

I would like to convert **ALL arrays** in a json via JOLT to a list of key-value pairs:

input:

```
"ex":{"arr": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]}
```

desired output:

```
"ex-arr-0": "1", 
"ex-arr-1": "2", ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it via the following:

```
{
    "*": 
    {
        "ex": {"*": {"*": "&3.&2-&1-&"}}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ex": {
        "arr": {
          "*": "ex-arr-&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```